# iOS Simulator won't use the same layout has macOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

It seems that for a very long time now I was unable to have the same keyboard layout on macOS in any of my iOS simulators.

Making every piece of text typed inside the iOS Simulator from my mac keyboard very painful for years now.

The issue seems to mostly impact nonstandard QWERTY US users, the default of the simulator.

There are already many SO answers about that matter, some are good, some outdated, or over-complicated.

The goal of this post is to provide easy access to the solution for future googlers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This message is for every wanderer, seeking a solution once in a while for years and giving up.

The proper steps to get the same layout are the following

---

###### 1. Identify your macOS keyboard layout

[image: keyboard layout]

###### 2. Make sure 'Use the Same Keyboard Language as macOS' is selected in the simulator

[image: Use the same keyboard language]

###### 3. Add a new keyboard (same as macOS) on your simulator under Settings > General > Keyboard

- in my case Français Canada / Canadian French)

[image: Keyboard]

###### 4. Toggle your simulators software keyboard somewhere there's an input

[image: Toggle simulator software keyboard]

###### 5. Select the right keyboard and voilà.

[image: Select the right layout]

###### 6. Enjoy the sheer pleasure of writing in your own layout inside the simulator.